# Optimal method to find perpendicular distance between numpy poly1d and arbitrary point

Tags: python, numpy

I have a [numpy.poly1d](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.poly1d.html) that can be any arbitrary 1d polynomial. Given an arbitrary point P, I wish to find the perpendicular distance between the curve and the point, and the point on the curve where the shortest distance line intersects the curve, *if the point P does not lie on the polynomial itself*

Now I can do something like the question [Distance between a point and a curve in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67490884/distance-between-a-point-and-a-curve-in-python), by sampling a set of points. But I believe that won't be fast enough considering that I have <100000 polynomials and <1000000 points per polynomial that I wish to find that distances to. Can someone suggest a more optimal method?

Here is a sample image illustration of what I am looking for. Basically, given P and B(t) I wish to find the length of g(x) and point Q.

[image]

Comment: What's the order of those polynomials? This question might be better suited for mathematics stackexchange.

Comment: So it can be anything from a line to a cubic Bezier curve

Comment: Because this is closely related to algorithms. You may also get more answers by searching/asking for an algorithm in https://cs.stackexchange.com/ if you haven't done it yet.